# adding google mini search box to mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have mediawiki 1.16 and a google mini search engine that indexes my WIki. How can I add the google search box  just below the Mediawiki search box that will allow my users to used the google mini search

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this extension http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RawMsg for adding any html on any page.

http://www.google.com/cse/ to make search for your own site.